# Residue by Laurent coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

If we say that
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_{n}\left(z-z_{0}\right)^{n}
$$
was the Laurent expansion of $f$ around a second order pole $z_{0}$ of $f$, can you then calculate the residue $Res_{z_{0}}f(z)^2$ of $f^{2}$ at $z_{0}$ from the Laurent coefficients $c_{-2}, c_{-1}, c_{0}$ and $c_{1}$ ?

Comment: Yes!  Write it out and distribute.  Collect terms of order $z^{-1}$.

Comment: No the residue (coefficient of $(z-z_0)^{-1}$) will be an infinite series